Change displayed timezone SMT by SGT in WordPress
I have a WordPress website where I have used the Events Calendar to display events. On the single event, I enter the event time and the timezone is Singapore. However, it displays SMT and I would like to use SGT which is more common.
The Events Calendar support team told me that this SMT timezone is from WordPress itself.
Is there a way to change the timezone as I want to display SGT and not SMT for Singapore timezone?

There's a Timezone setting in the Settings → General section. You can set it to a specific city or you can set it to a GMT offset. I'm not sure what the difference between SMT and SGT is, though.

Thanks, @PatJ. I know WordPress lets you set timezones in General Settings. However, Events Calendar displays Singapore timezone as SMT instead of SGT, which is confusing. Even after testing other timezones in the General Settings, SMT still appears. Events Calendar support says this comes from core WordPress files. Is there a way to display SGT instead? SGT is commonly used, while SMT isn’t.

according to wikipedia, Singapour time (SGT) and Malaysia time (SMT) are on the same timezone UTC + 8 since 1982. then we don't understand the difference that you make between these two, edit your question to give us more details, screenshots, etc.

My question is very simple: Why WordPress display SMT and not SGT for Singapore Timezone? And is there a way to change it, and if yes how?
